# How to discover current partition in slurm?

Tags: partition, slurm

How can we discover the partition of an active node using slurm?

For example, `sinfo` lists the partitions and the nodes, but the hope is to use a query command which returns the partition of an active node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While on the node you can execute command env and search for the value of environment variable SLURM_JOB_PARTITION. It will be equal to the partition this node belongs to:

```
env | grep SLURM_JOB_PARTITION
```

Comment: or `echo $SLURM_JOB_PARTITION`